# Dialogflow dialog mode dropped?

Tags: dialogflow-es

We have been using the template mode for intent training phrases for a while.  But as of yesterday, we can no longer create new templates (clicking on the " icon used to toggle to @ but not any more).  There is a bubble saying that this feature has been deprecated but there is nothing in the release notes ... anyone can shed some light on this?

-rg

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing when I found your question...  :-/  Although deprecated, if you still need to use a training phrase template, you can download the intent (download icon on the intent row when you're seeing the list of intents), search for `userSays[ ].isTemplate`. You can set it to `true` there, and upload your intent back to dialogflow (list of intents screen, next to `Create Intent`, you'll find an `Upload intent` option). Hope it helps in the meantime.

Comment: Dialogflow support confirmed that template mode has been dropped.  No release notes were provided (or other release process it seems).  Fortunately, they did maintain some level of backwards compatibility: existing agents with template intents will continue to work, and they can be exported/imported (as pointed out by @maganap).

Answer (score 0):

Per Dialogflow support template mode has been dropped.